# Error: Permission denied to access property "toString", Firefox Mac only

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, permission-denied

Some sort of issue with Firefox browser only.  I have a jQuery handler for an input element on the page that basically does this:

```
function() {
  $(this).parent().find("label").css({
    "background-color": "#000"
  })
}
```

That is directly from the handler in the developer toolbar.  The handler is executing, but the console is showing the Permission denied to access property "toString".  I've seen a number of other posts regarding this issue in Firefox (I don't see that error in Safari or Chrome on a Mac), but those don't really provide a solution for my issue.  I tried disabling a number of plugin and add-ons, but still have the problem.

Here is some more detail:

HTML:

```
<div class="printreportwrapper">
<section data-section-name="Other findings">
    <header class="level2">Other findings</header>
    <p>
        <label for="T3_48" style="background-color: transparent;">Liver:</label>
        <input id="T3_48" name="T3_48" value="Normal." type="text">
    </p>
    . . .
    . . .
</section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".printreportwrapper input").on("mouseleave", function() {$(this).parent().find("label").css({"background-color" : "transparent"})});
$(".printreportwrapper input").on("mouseenter",function() {$(this).parent().find("label").css({"background-color" : "#555"})});
```

It actually may be completely unrelated to all of that, since if I detach the handler from the input fields there I still see the error in the FF developer tools, and when I click on the error link to the right, it brings me to one of my stylesheets:

```
 <style type="text/css">

    .vieweroverlay {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        . . .
        . . .
    }
</style>
```

This is the error in FF dev:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "toString"[Learn More] My_telerad:90:5
    handleMouseoverEvent https://sscotti.net/pro/My_telerad:90:5
```

and that points to the CSS mentioned above.  It doesn't appear to be related to the handlers.

Comment: Can you provide more code (corresponding HTML and whole JS). If the handler is called from an event, like a `click` or `focus` or something, then `$(this)` is maybe the event and not the element itself and finding the parent causes the error.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what problem you're facing. If you know what code FF is objecting to, perhaps you can clarify the problem statement. If you're not sure what's causing the error, then tracking down the source of the error could be a useful first step. Use a process of elimination and remove code (JavaScript, CSS, HTML) until the error goes away.

Comment: I'll keep looking.  It appears to be only a FF issue, so maybe it is related to some add ons or extensions that I have installed for FF.

Answer (score 0):

I had been got a same problem from yesterday.
My Suggest is try disable some add ons or extensions.
In my case, "All MyTube" was the cause.